# How to override element.style attribute ? (overflow: hidden)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have the following situation:

[image]

As you can see in the right of the image, there is an attribute (overflow: hidden) which is overriding my own attribute (overflow-x and overflow-y). I want to remove overflow: hidden but I haven't access to "ion-scroll" element which is aplying this style. There is some way to remove (overflow: hidden) to allow me apply my two attributes (overflow-x and overflow-y) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from the style sheet, you need !important, else reset style with javascript , it will override inline style  see https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: If I do this (overflow: hidden !important;), overflow:hidden is removed but "overflow-x: scroll" and "overflow-y: hidden" keep disabled. If I disable "overflow: hidden" manually on developer tools, before applying "overflow: hidden !important", it turns on overflow-x and overflow-y, but with overflow: hidden !important they keep disabled.

Comment: Add !important to each of the overflow-x and overflow-y, and take the !important off the bare overflow.

Comment: nop, did you understand the use of !important ? it should be behind your new rules !

Comment: also try direct inline css, I am not sure what has better priority, full inline css rule or the "important!".

Comment: Thanks everyone. This attribute was being added automatically with overflow: auto. The solution was implement "overflow: auto !important". But I only reached this solution by your provided answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely do not want to use `!important` because if you understand CSS and how the cascade works with specificity, you can achieve this using best practices.

This is how the CSS cascade and specificity works:

```
Elements are worth 1
Classes are worth 10
ID's are worth 100
Inline styles are worth 1000
!important acts as an override to specificity
```

When these are combined on the stylesheet, specificty adds together.
An element, with a class `.className a` has a specificity of 11.
An element, with an ID `#idName a` has a specificity of 101. 
An element, inside of a classed element, inside of an element with an ID would have 111 specificity and so on.

The highest specificty always wins unless two lines of CSS have the same specificity, the LAST line takes priority.

Just using !important to overtake any specificty is not a good practice a because if your code is ever handed over or needs to be updated, it's going to be nearly impossible to overwrite.

Although it will work, Inline CSS is not recommended either, as best practices use an external style sheet.

If possible, Go into your CSS file, find the line that corresponds to what needs to be over written, and make it as specific as possible going down the dom.

If not then yes you will have to do it with an inline style.

This is the correct way to update and override CSS styles.

Comment: And how do inline styles fit into the CSS cascade and specificity? That's what the OP is relating to

Answer (score 2):

You must add `!important` to your own `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` attributes, so those will have more relevance that the `overflow` from `ion-scroll`